# aws codecommit Throttled: too many concurrent connections

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I have 11 git repositories in aws codecommit. I am using ssh to connect.

As part of a release, I need to checkout different branches, do pushes, merges, etc on these 11 repos. But, I keep getting the error "Throttled: too many concurrent connections."

There doesn't seem to be any [quota/limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/limits.html) on concurrent connections. I am not sure how to disconnect any previous connections. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by sleeping for few seconds in-between git calls in my bash script. We just need to slow down the speed.